# Extracting packet features using wireshark

Tags: java, wireshark

I am trying to extract or determine features like pay load, sequence
number, hop count, hop addresses, time to live in a packet using Wireshark. I got ttl value, source and destination addresses, but I am not able to find the payload, hop count, hop address etc.

Is there any way I can read these values from wireshark file using a java program, and display them in a Java frame?

Comment: What sort of help do you need? This is extremely broad at the moment. Show your code and explain a specific problem.

Comment: actually I haven't started writing code. I was first looking for the features using wireshark, I have got the packet IP features but features like hop count and hop address etc are not there. So if you have any idea how can i get these values in the wireshark, it will be very helpful. And i am just asking is it possible to connect wireshark with a java interface. because writing these values manually for every packet is time consuming and a head ache. :/

Comment: It is two questions. _NEVER_ ask two questions in a single one!

Answer (score 1):

If by "hop addresses" you mean that you want the network or MAC addresses of each router through which a packet traveled when going from the source to the destination, neither Wireshark nor any other packet analyzer on the planet can, in the general case, determine that, because that information isn't recorded in the packet!

There is an IPv4 "record route" option that, if added to the packet when it is sent, will cause routers to add their address to the route when they transmit the packet; however, there's no simple switch to turn that on - the program sending the packets would have to be modified to request that, if the operating system on which it's running supports doing so.

Comment: ohkay.. that means hop addresses ain't possible to get. What about hop count? I can't see it either in wireshark and yeah payload too.

Comment: The closest thing to a hop count in IP is the time-to-live field; however, that's a field given an *arbitrary* value when it's sent from the original host, and *decremented* for each hop, with the packet being discarded rather than forwarded if the time-to-live value is zero when the packet is received (and it might be decremented by more than 1, as, according to [RFC 791](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791), it's in units of seconds).  So the hop count isn't possible to get, either (except by counting hops in the "record route" option *IF* it's present).

Comment: okay.. thanks for the help. but that means I can't implement this method requiring these values.

Comment: Correct.  If you want to determine what hops a packet took to get to you, you can do that only if the packet was an IPv4 packet with the "record route" option added to it when it was initially sent; IPv6 has no such option as far as I know ([one was proposed in 2000](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kitamura-ipv6-record-route-00), but it never left the Internet-Draft stage).  You are probably trying to solve some broader problem; ask a question about that problem, in as broad terms as possible, rather than asking how to implement a particular solution.